# function calling in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show div whose id is deliveryto1 when if condition is true it doesn't show deliverto1 div. This div(#deliverto1) is always showing in else part.

```
 $('#delivery').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
      $('#deliverto1').show();  
      $('#deliverto').hide();

    } else {
          $('#areas').show()
          $('#deliverto').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post your html code as well?

Comment: can you also post your css so we can see the initial visability of the elements

Comment: <div class="col-per-50" id="deliverto">                           @if (ViewBag.CanDeliver)
{
  <p class="font_size" style="margin-bottom:55px">
   Delivery to : </p>
   <p>@Session["CustomerAddress"] <span>. &nbsp</span> @Session["CustomerPostCode"] 
  </p>
  }
  else
  {
   <p class="font_size">
    Delivery to :</p>
   <br />
  <p>Collection
  </p>
  }

Comment: div class="col-per-50" id="deliverto1" style="display:none">
                        
                            <p class="font_size" style="margin-bottom:55px">
                                Delivery to :  </p>
                            <h4>Collection</h4>
                            
                        </div>

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to hide div in else part. Use `.hide()` in else part as shown below

```
$('#delivery').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
      $('#deliverto1').show();  
      $('#deliverto').hide();

    } else {
          $('#areas').show()
          $('#deliverto').show();
          $('#deliverto1').hide(); 
    }
});
```